# How do I create a white mask displaying only black in an image?

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to get the outline of an album cover and edge detectors (Canny, Laplace) pick up too much noise. I don't fully understand how image masking works and would like put a white mask over the image so I see only the black pixels

I have applied a GaussianBlur 5x5 and converted the image to hsv values. I have a range of values which are black, and I have filtered these out.

```py
# imported image and processing (shorthand here)
image = cv2.imread(args["image"])
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(image, (5,5), 0)
blur_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(blur, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# set regions of color 
boundaries = [
    # black 
    ([0,0,0],[180, 255, 40])

    #pink
    #([151, 80, 50], [174, 255, 255])   
]

# loop over the boundaries
for (lower, upper) in boundaries:
    # create NumPy arrays from the boundaries
    lower = np.array(lower, dtype = "uint8")
    upper = np.array(upper, dtype = "uint8")

    # find the colors within the specified boundaries and apply
    mask = cv2.inRange(blur_hsv, lower, upper)  
    output = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask = mask)

    # show the images
    cv2.imshow("images", np.hstack([image, output]))
```

I was hoping for some distinction in the final output, but the window is just black. How can I create a different color mask?

Edit:

Not the exact image, but a sample LEFT: original; RIGHT: processed

[image: Test Marker Outline Image + Output]

Comment: Could you add your input image and expected output image?

Comment: Post has been updated with a sample image output

Comment: I don't fully understand what you're trying to do. Do you want to create a mask that highlights all the black pixels (so any black pixels will be white on the mask)?

Comment: @nathancy -- the opposite. the mask is currently black, so it turns all the pixels that are not "black" black, and I can't see which ones it has detected as "black." I want a white mask over those pixels instead

Comment: So you want to create a mask where all non-black pixels are white. When the mask is bitwise-and with the original image, you just want a resulting image that only show colors?

Answer (score 4):

From my understanding, you want to obtain a mask where all colored pixels (non-black) are white. When we use `cv2.inRange()`, we give it a lower/upper threshold that returns all pixels within the bounds in **white**. Then when we use `cv2.bitwise_and()` with the mask and the original image, the resulting image will be the areas where **both** the mask and original image are white. Essentially any pixels in white are the areas that we want to keep.

Your current output shows all areas in the original picture that have pixels between the lower/upper threshold. But if your goal is to display all non-black pixels, then you can simply invert the mask. Here's a visualization:

Here's your current mask and represents all pixels within the thresholds in the original image as white.

[image]

We can simply invert the mask or use `cv2.bitwise_not()` to get your desired mask. This new mask represents all colored pixels not within your lower/upper threshold as white. Therefore this mask is all the colored pixels.

```
final_mask = 255 - mask
```

[image]

Remember, any pixels that we want to keep, we should make it white whereas any pixels we want to throw away, we make it black. So if we `cv2.bitwise_and()` this new mask with the original image, we get this

[image]

Here's a good [tutorial on bitwise operations and masking](https://datacarpentry.org/image-processing/04-drawing-bitwise/)

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread('1.png')
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(image, (5,5), 0)
blur_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(blur, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# create NumPy arrays from the boundaries
lower = np.array([0,0,0], dtype = "uint8")
upper = np.array([180,255,40], dtype = "uint8")

# find the colors within the specified boundaries and apply
mask = cv2.inRange(blur_hsv, lower, upper)  
mask = 255 - mask
output = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask = mask)

# show the images
cv2.imshow("output", output)
cv2.imshow("mask", mask)
cv2.waitKey()
```